# Big snapshot of small portion of screen?

Tags: screenshot

I know about taking snapshot using PrtSc button , also its usage with shift to take snaps of a rectangle drawn over area of interest but in such a case the image created remains exactly of the size of the rectangle drawn. Consider the case of taking a snap of terminal output of a command. Such an image remains very small and hard to see. How can I take snap of small portion of a window but create a big image ?

this is the snap i caught using Shift + PrtSc
[image]

Comment: This seems a relatively uncommon requirement, so I suspect the answer is that you subsequently scale the image up using the graphics tool of your choice (`gimp`, `mogrify`, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download Shutter from the Software Center, you can save the screen shot at any size you want:
[image]

You may want to resize your Terminal window first to catch the outpunt in a smaller window.